# cannot satisfy return type for typescript typed function

Tags: typescript

Say I have this type:

```
  export type Transformer = <T extends any[], U>(
    data: T,
  ) => U;
```

THen I have this function which I want to conform to this type:

```
export const transform: Transformer = (
  data: Result[]
): { data:Result[] } => {
  if (!data) {
    return { data: [] };
  }


  data.forEach((record:Result) => {
    record.extraStuff = {
      foo: 'bar'
    };
  });

  return { data: data };
};
```

The compiler complains with:

```
Type '(data: Result[]) => { data: RecordMatchingSearchResult[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Transformer'.
  Type '{ data: Result[]; }' is not assignable to type 'U'.
```

Do I need to add a generic constraint to U to make it inferred.

I also did not write the type but it seems a bit weird that it does not accept generic arguments but they exist on the function instead.

Comment: `U` does not have any type constraint .. what should be the type of `U`? is it really required to use `U` here?as you are accepting only 1 input in your function.

Comment: so I tried to add `, TOutputType extends { data: any[] }>(` to say it should have a `an attribute named data which holds an array of any but it did not work.

Comment: Why do you need to use that type?  It's nearly impossible to implement correctly.  A caller can call `transform<string[], number>(["hey"])` or `transform<string[], boolean>(["hey"])` and expect to receive a `number` result in the first case and a `boolean` in the second case.  But at runtime they are the same, so your implementation will never be able to figure out which type to return.  The only types compatible with all possible `U` are `never` and `any`, so you can either throw an exception (`never`) or give up on type safety (`any`).  That's probably not the intent, so why use that type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your function is that it is not really generic. You have a generic function signature ( `Transformer` ) and you try to assign a function that is not generic at all.

The problem occurs with the return type specifically because the return type must be specified by the caller, so the caller will expect the return type it specified not your non generic result ( `{ data: Result[] }`). If your assignment was allowed this call would cause a runtime error:

```
let result = transform<Result[], { other: number }>([]);
result.other // this would cause an error
```

If the type of the result is fixed you should just declare it, and the function implementation itself should be generic:

```
export type Transformer = <T extends { extraStuff: any }>(
    data: T[],
) => { data: T[] };

class Result {
    extraStuff: any;
}
export const transform: Transformer = <T extends { extraStuff: any }>(data: T[]): { data: T[] } => {
    if (!data) {
        return { data: [] };
    }


    data.forEach((record: T) => {
        record.extraStuff = {
            foo: 'bar'
        };
    });

    return { data: data };
};
```

Or you could move the generics of the `Transfomer` from the function signature to the type, and specify the type arguments when you declare the `transform` function and so the functions itself would not have to be generic:

```
export type Transformer<T extends { extraStuff: any }, U> = (
    data: T[],
) => U;

export const transform: Transformer<Result, { data: Result[] }> = (data: Result[]): { data: Result[] } => {
    if (!data) {
        return { data: [] };
    }


    data.forEach((record: T) => {
        record.extraStuff = {
            foo: 'bar'
        };
    });

    return { data: data };
};
```

Comment: Here you are bounding the return type to the input, which I think  was not the original intention. I think this function cannot be formulated in a generic way, so I was wondering why is your solution is any better than `export type Transformer = <T extends any[]>(data: T) => any;`?

Comment: @Wickoo, the implementation ties the result to the input. Not sure what the intent was behind the original `Transformer` signature was. You could use `any` but that is generally something I avoid as it defeats the point of Typescript. I added a different version that keeps the generic parameters, and you can specify them on the type.

Comment: I agree that using `any` is not good, but when the generic argument cannot be inferred via arguments, specifying the generic type is as good as a cast. It doesn't provide any runtime safety, but in some cases it's more convenient to do so.

Comment: @Wickoo I agree, explicit type arguments are not a great way to code, but at least in this case you won't be left with a function that returns `any` so .. better then nothing :). I think the code fragment provided is not really enough to suggest a good solution. I'm just trying to point out why the error occurs (the main part of the question) and trying to point at a good direction. I don't think `any` is a good direction :)

Comment: moving the generics off the type was the answer.